# What is the best option when Windows 10 pops up a "scan drive for errors" message?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

On my machine, the Windows 10 notification center began popping up a "scan drive for errors" message.  I'd include a screenshot for context, but my reputation isn't high enough.

I clicked it, and shortly thereafter it popped up a similar message telling me I needed to reboot.  After doing so, on boot, a scan kicked off showing the message "Scanning and repairing drive (C:)" (again, sorry I can't include the screenshot for context).

Most other similar reports I found online seem to show a progress %, but I let it run for over 30 minutes and this never appeared for me.  I had a meeting and after a bit of googling, hard power cycled.  Thankfully, my computer came back up fine after that.  I haven't seen the warning since.

Still, it seems like I ought to do a scan of some kind.  There are lots of ways chkdsk and other similar utilities can be used to do similar checks.  I'm curious what people would recommend.  These are my main care-abouts:

- Scans and fixes issues as safely, completely, and quickly as possible.
- Shows progress.
- Is a tool that comes with Windows 10 - I generally distrust 3rd-party utilities, as they could more easily be or contain a trojan.

Thank you!

Comment: "I'm curious what people would recommend." - Replace the disk.

Comment: First, do your best to backup anything that matters to you.  Probably best to do from a  boot USB or CD or from another machine.  You should not trust your hard disk unless you can first  definitively rule it out.  I also wouldn't rely on windows tools to `fix`  this issue.  If your disk is failing you are operating on borrowed uptime and should allocate that window appropriately.

Comment: As noted, time to replace the drive. Back up first and then scan with CHKDSK for errors.

Comment: you can of course open command window and run chkdsk without the /f option to see if it detects errors. You can not fix them like that, but it should be able to detect and show you errors.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody in comments already said - make sure your backup is solid before going any further.

To actually get past the message, you have to let it run chkdsk until it is happy. You may need to reboot once more for it to run a second time before it will clear the flag. You should not interrupt it once it is running. Only when the OS has decided the disk is clean will it clear the flag that keeps asking you to check it.
30 minutes is nothing… let it run overnight, then once it's finished, run chkdsk again manually from the command line to see if it needs to run again next boot. If so, allow it & reboot. You cannot rush this process.

The reason you need your backup in place first is that chkdsk's job is not to save your files if they're corrupt… it is to fix the disk's file tables.
It will sacrifice any & all of your data in order to do this. It does not care at all about your data, only the file tables.

Comment: Just to expand on "It does not care at all about your data, only the file tables." You'll see various files with .chk extension after chkdsk finishes. These are the remains of files and fragments Windows could not recover, and usually cannot be used for further recovery: https://www.howtogeek.com/282798/what-are-the-found000-folder-and-file0000chk-file-in-windows/ . Make a **disk image first,** so that you have another chance to recover data lost by chkdsk. BTW, check HDD S.M.A.R.T. data -- I've had *applications* occasionally mangle the file system, and the *disk* was fine after repair.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Based on this though, once I have my backup, I'm not entirely clear what action you're recommending I take.  Should I wait for the check to pop back up?  Thus far that has not happened, so I was wondering if I should be more proactive than this.  Putting my question a bit more concretely, should I run chkdsk?  If so, is there an optimal set of options for such a circumstance?  Or is there another tool (preferably that still comes with Windows 10) that would be better?

Comment: Once you have your backup the drive is then disposable. Do whatever it takes to try fix it, including chkdsk &/or reformat. You're safe now.

Answer (score 0):

You first action should be to verify the health of your disk :
Check its SMART data using a product such as
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).
If the numbers are bad, the disk needs to be replaced.
If you are not sure, add a screenshot to your post with the SMART
attributes and we will have a look at it.

Second, if the SMART attributes are not a complete disaster,
save your data that is on the disk (for which you don't have a backup).
Save as much as you can, as long as the disk works correctly.

If this is a hard disk and not an SSD, format it using slow format
(not quick). This may take a long time for a large disk.
Then check again its SMART values.

If everything is fine, you may return the data to the disk.
In case of failure, replace the disk.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others that suggest checking SMART, I'd like to add the possibility to run chkdsk from a command prompt (use Admin option) without the /f switch. It will not be able to fix errors but might show you what it thinks is wrong with the file system.

With regards to SMART and chkdsk: They are very different tools. While SMART shows you what the drive reports about itself, it is totally oblivious to the file system. Chkdsk's concern on the other hand is a consistent file system.

SMART showing worrying stats does not say anything about the file system, while file system inconsistenties can happen on a perfectly healthy drive. But of course those two aspects can't be seen entirely separately, a strategically placed bad sector can knock out an important piece of file system meta data.

Answer (score 0):

First, chkdsk is published by Microsoft, but some virus or ransomware (such as Petya) will make its own process look like chkdsk. But it usually doesn't take that long. Secondly, terminating the process might cause trouble to your computer and disk. You should wait longer. If it keeps running for a long time, you can turn off your computer and boot from a recovery drive or PE. Scan for viruses, than use chkdsk in the terminal or other tools (like SMART) to check your disk.